# I want to know whether I've been writing it correctly and how can I write it in a different way?

Tags: word-choice

Is "If said in the words of Mike:" correct?

How can I substitute "in this way" or "the following way"?

Comment: Can you please provide some context for the second part of your question?

Comment: I've been writing an article in which I have to cite many times. This is the context. For example, before quoting Mike, I have to mention that the following is the remark of Mike.

Comment: Understood. You can refer my answer where I have suggested an alternative.

Comment: I think you are looking for  things that someone says or writes. If so, try this : ***" In someone's words"*** or ***"In someone's own words"***. e.g. *"In judge's words, he was an evil man."*

Comment: Are "In the words of Mike:" and "To quote Mike:" correct? I have to quote using inverted commas. And, can I leave inverted commas if I say "In the words of mike..." or "To quote Mike..."? Can I start a sentence with "To" e.g. "To quote mike"?

Comment: I'd use 'As Mike puts it:' or 'Mike puts it this way:'.

Comment: There's really only one way to write "it".

Answer (score 1):

*No*

You can simply say,

> In the words of Mike...

because the above sentence emphasizes that Mike has already said something and you are quoting him.

Or you can entirely rephrase your sentence.

> To quote Mike...

is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you're quoting Mike and only Mike in your article, you can use quotation marks to delineate his words. For example, you could write something like this:

> During the press conference today, Mike spoke about the problem with late trains. Apparently, the weather is much to blame. Mike said, "In the fall, leaves from the trees make the rails slippery." But that's not the only season that causes trouble. "In the winter, we have to deal with snow, and ice will cause the switches to freeze."
>
> Even in the summertime, Mike finds a way to blame the weather. "The heat causes the rails to expand. So, trains [have to go extra slow] to keep from derailing".

This make it clear to the reader, which words are yours and which are Mike's. Because Mike is the only other speaker, you can mix your words and his by just using quotations marks. If more speakers were involved, you'd need to say who is speaking each time, either before or after the quoted section.

Note how in that last sentence, I used square brackets around "have to go extra slow". That means those aren't his exact words — it's kind of like excluding them from the quotation marks. Mike may have said something more complicated or difficult to understand about the speed of the trains. This is a way to shorten or simplify what he said, but still keep it within his quotation. (Of course, it should mean— in essence — the same thing Mike actually said.)

Regarding the phrases "in the words of Mike" or "to quote Mike", yes, they're correct, although typically used in a limited context — they're more grandiose and tend to elevate the speaker, such as:

> In the words of Tennyson: "'Tis better to have loved and lost than never to have loved at all."
>
> To quote Shakespeare: "Love all, trust a few, do wrong to none."

If you did use "In the words of Mike", it's something that you'd only want to use once in the article. More commonly used is a simple "Mike says" or "Mike said", especially if it's something you're writing about first-hand. A lot depends on the nature of your article and where you're getting Mike's words.